# unix script to exit from oracle error when using a wait statement

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I have a ksh shell script that runs a .sql script with a background and wait statement. Is it possible for me to capture the generic "ORA-0" error and exit out completely?

So far:

```
$ORACLE_BASE/bin/sqlplus 2.sql &
pid2=$!
echo "Waiting for PID:$pid2"
wait $pid2
#look for error here
#exit program if oracle error
```

Comment: How do you run your sql script ? With SQL*Plus ?

Comment: yes, sqlplus within the script. i will add this to my question. thanks

Comment: In this particular example, running SQL*Plus in the background serves no useful purpose.  Simply run it in the foreground if you do not have anything else to perform in parallel while it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL*Plus is kind of a shell itself, so it catches the errors from oracle and continues execution. You want to look at the SQL*Plus command [WHENEVER SQLERROR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12052.htm#sthref2523), especially [WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12023.htm#i2697968) that allows to exit immediately with an error code.

So, at the beginning of your .sql script you add something like :

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
```

And if there is an SQL error it will exit with the relevant error code.

Now, in the shell script after the `wait` you can get the error by reading `$?`.

Something like (depending on the exact syntax of your shell) :

```
wait $pid2
ret=$?
if [ $ret != 0 ]  # if not success
then
    exit $ret     # propagate error code
fi
```

Comment: So it will exit the sql with an error code. So, what I need to do is once it exits that sql statement, it will also  exit from the shell program itself. I need something to handle that as well.

Comment: `cmd; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ...` is more idiomatically written `if ! cmd; then ...` or simply `cmd || ...`